# Java: How to implement Word Break?

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, word-break

I'm trying to understanding the following Java + Dynamic Programming implementation (https://pingzhblog.wordpress.com/2015/09/17/word-break/):

```
public class Solution {
    public boolean wordBreak(String s, Set<String> wordDict) {
        if(s == null) {
            return false;
        }

        boolean[] wordBreakDp = new boolean[s.length() + 1];
        wordBreakDp[0] = true;
        for(int i = 1; i <= s.length(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                String word = s.substring(j, i);
                if(wordBreakDp[j] && wordDict.contains(word)) {
                    wordBreakDp[i] = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }//end for i
        return wordBreakDp[s.length()];
    }
}
```

But need some clarification with `String s = "abcxyz"` and `Set <String> wordDict = ["z", "xy", "ab", "c"]`.

I'm still unclear as to what `wordBreakDp[]` represents, and setting one to true means.

So I made the attempt and got `wordBreakDP[2,3,5,6]=true`, but what do those indexes tell? Couldn't I have just checked for `i=6` since all we are checking is if last index of `wordBreakDp[]` is true, `wordBreakDp[s.length()];`?

And say for example I got `ab` for `s.substring(0, 2);`, but then how can we just assume that next loop, `s.substring(1, 2);`, is not useful and just `break;` out of the loop?

Thank you

Comment: It looks like wordBreakDP[n] = true means that a word from the dictionary ends at that index into the string (if the indexes start at 1) AND wordBreakDP [index of the start of THAT word-1] is also true.  But that second index is only true if a word ends at that index and the index of the start of that word -1 is also true, and so on, until you get to the -1 index, which is always set to true.  Therefore, if after going through those loops, the last index is set to true, that means the string s has been successfully broken up into words from wordDict.

Comment: The 2,3,5,6 means that a word ends at index 2 ("ab"), a word ends at index 3 ("c"), a word ends at index 5 ("xy") and a word ends at index 6 ("z").

Comment: As for your last thought about breaking out of the loop, you could try with wordDict = ["z", "xy", "ab", "a", "ba"] and s="aba" to see what happens (You could segment "aba" into "a" and "ba" or "ab" and "a"), so maybe the algorithm just chooses whichever one it happens upon first.

Comment: @DavidChoweller Appreciate the insight. For more clarification, why is it that if wordBreakDP[n] is true then wordBreakDP [index of the start of THAT word-1] is also true?

Comment: It's actually the other way round.  It is only if the index of the start of the word - 1 is true that wordBreakDp at the end of the word is set to true.  This is how the algorithm works.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but it might be helpful in understanding the loops.  It prints the value of substring(i,j) and also wordBreakDp[j] at each iteration.  It also prints the final solution (segmentation) at the end of the method.

```
public boolean wordBreak(String s, Set<String> wordDict) {
    if(s == null) {
        return false;
    }

    boolean[] wordBreakDp = new boolean[s.length() + 1];
    wordBreakDp[0] = true;
    for(int i = 1; i <= s.length(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {

            String word = s.substring(j, i);
            System.out.println("["+j+","+i+"]="+s.substring(j,i)+", wordBreakDP["+j+"]="+wordBreakDp[j]);
            if(wordBreakDp[j] && wordDict.contains(word)) {
                wordBreakDp[i] = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }//end for i
    for (int i = 1, start=0; i <= s.length(); i++) {
        if (wordBreakDp[i]) {
            System.out.println(s.substring(start,i));
            start = i;
        }
    }
    return wordBreakDp[s.length()];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the answer to your last question, which was:

> And say for example I got ab for s.substring(0, 2);, but then how can
>   we just assume that next loop, s.substring(1, 2);, is not useful and
>   just break; out of the loop?

You are right that if you got "ab" for s.substring(0,2) and you break out of the loop, this doesn't necessarily mean that s.substring(1,2) is not useful.  Let's say that s.substring(1,2) *is* useful.  This means that "a" is also a valid word, and so is "b".  The solution found by this algorithm would start with "ab" whereas the solution found by *not* breaking would be "a" followed by "b".  Both these solutions are correct (assuming that the rest of the string can be broken into valid words as well).  The algorithm doesn't find *all* valid solutions.  It just returns true if the string *can* be broken into valid words, i.e., if there is one solution that satisfies the condition.  There may be more than one solution, of course, but that is not the purpose of this algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

**Note, `f[i]` means whether the first `i` characters of `s` is valid.** An example,

> String = `catsand`
>
> Dict = `[cat, cats, sand, and]`

```
 s =     c a t s a n d
dp =   T F F T T F F ?
 i =   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
                     *
```

> Note `dp[0]` is True, because empty string is valid. Say we have `dp[0]` through `dp[6]`.
>
> Let's calculate `dp[7]`, which denotes whether `catsand` is valid.

**For `catsand` to be valid, there must be a non-empty suffix that is in dict, AND the remaining prefix is valid.**

```
"catsand" is a valid, if:

  If "" is valid, and "catsand" is inDict, or
  If "c" is valid, and "atsand" is inDict, or
  If "ca" is valid, and "tsand" is inDict, or
  If "cat" is valid, and "sand" is inDict, or
  If "cats" is valid, and "and" is inDict, or
  If "catsa" is valid, and "nd" is inDict, or
  If "catsan" is valid, and "d" is inDict
```

Translated to pesudo code:

```
dp[7] is True, if:
        j               j  i
  If dp[0] && inDict( s[0..7) ) or
  If dp[1] && inDict( s[1..7) ) or
  If dp[2] && inDict( s[2..7) ) or
  If dp[3] && inDict( s[3..7) ) or
  If dp[4] && inDict( s[4..7) ) or
  If dp[5] && inDict( s[5..7) ) or
  If dp[6] && inDict( s[6..7) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Solution {
    public int wordBreak(String a, ArrayList<String> b) {
        int n = a.length();
        boolean dp[] = new boolean[n+1];
        dp[0] = true;
        for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
            if(!dp[i])continue;
            for(String s : b){
                int len = s.length();
                int end = len + i;
                if(end > n || dp[end])continue;
                if(a.substring(i,end).equals(s)){
                    dp[end] = true;
                }

            }
        }
        if(dp[n])return 1;
        else return 0;
    }
}
```